# Call to undefined function curl_file_create() [file handling]

Tags: php, file-upload, curl

I'm trying to upload a file with curl, and in the PHP documentation it says:

> To post a file, prepend a filename with @ and use the full path. The filetype can be explicitly specified by following the filename with the type in the format ';type=mimetype'. This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data. As of PHP 5.2.0, value must be an array if files are passed to this option with the @ prefix. As of PHP 5.5.0, the @ prefix is deprecated and files can be sent using CURLFile.

So I try using CURLFile instead, whereas I get the error

> Call to undefined function curl_file_create()

so - then I try to locate the class CURLFile with
`var_dump(class_exists('curlfile'));`

But it says that it doesn't.
I wonder - is CURLFile something one has to install manually?
And is it better to use the @path/to/file;type=mime instead, even though it will be deprecated soon enough?

Thank you

To clairy - curl is installed and works. It's only the file-handling mumbo jumbo that doesn't seem to exist on my system.

I don't add any code, cause there is no code to add.
I run `curl_file_create()` and get the answer that the function doesn't exists, even though curl itself works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not use "curl_file_create" and "CurlFile", I prefer to use "@/file_name_with_full_path".

See the reference links and use these other methods for file upload via POST method via CURL via PHP.

[Send a file via post with curl and PHP](http://blog.derakkilgo.com/2009/06/07/send-a-file-via-post-with-curl-and-php/)

Comment: as of PHP 5.5, the @ prefix is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

PHP must have been compiled with the `--with-curl` switch for this function to be available.  Check your `phpinfo()` output to verify what switches your PHP was compiled with.

If you are on Linux then check your distribution's packages as Curl support may be provided by a module instead.  (For example, on Debian one must install the `php5-curl` package.)

---

Note that `curl_file_create()` was added in PHP 5.5.0.  If your PHP installation is older, it will not support this function.

Comment: curl works just fine. It's just the file-handling that doesn't.

Comment: @rm- This is not clear at all from your question.  It would be helpful to show a bit of code as well as the error you receive and on what line you receive it, as your question seems to indicate that you are trying to use a feature not supported by your PHP installation.  Nowhere in your question do you mention that your problem is with file-handling, and you don't show any example code to indicate what you are trying.  Even the *title* of your question is misleading.

Comment: The title is exactly the problem. The problem isn't the code, or the installation.

And since I also actually write that whats breaking is curl**file** and not **curl** itself, since I also asks about the @path/to/file-part... nevermind. There's no need to take it personal or anything.
And - I updated the question with that curl works and that it's only the filehandling that is the issue.

Comment: If the title is in fact the problem then this means that Curl is not supported by your PHP installation, as I have already said.  I don't know what else it *could* mean, unless you are using an old PHP that doesn't support this particular function.  What version of PHP do you have?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using xampp or wamp than you have to update php.ini file to enable curl because apache has separate php.ini file in its folder which it uses.the web server php.ini file is different from the php.ini in php installation folder.